# Преобразовать секунды в дату

Tags: 1с, время, дата

Есть время, переданное из вне по средствам веб-сервиса.
Это время записано в виде строки "Date(1404158409000)". По факту это миллисекунды прошедшие с 1 января 1970 года GMT+0.
Как в 1С из этого числа 1404158409000 получить время ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Так](http://bit.ly/TSbOVO):

```
unixtime = 1404158409000/1000;
Дата1С = Дата(1970,1,1,1,0,0) + unixtime;// 30.06.2014 21:00:09
```

Comment: Спасибо, не подумал что такие операции с датами можно делать...